Is there sexual innuendo in the story of Yael and Sisera?
In Judges 4, Barak leads the Israelite army and defeats the Canaanites in battle. The Canaanite general, Sisera, flees the battle and ends up at the tent of Yael, who is identified as the wife of Heber the Kenite. Yael encourages Sisera to enter her tent twice and promises him that he's safe:

(V18) Yael came out to greet Sisera and said to him, “Come in, my lord, come in here, do not be afraid.” So he entered her tent, and she covered him with a blanket.

Sisera asks for water, and Yael instead gives him milk. Later Deborah seems to employ exaggeration and sexually suggestive language during her victory song:

מַיִם שָׁאַל חָלָב נָתָנָה בְּסֵפֶל אַדִּירִים הִקְרִיבָה חֶמְאָה
Water he asked, milk she gave; she brought him curds in a lordly bowl
בֵּין רַגְלֶיהָ כָּרַע נָפַל שָׁכָב בֵּין רַגְלֶיהָ כָּרַע נָפָל בַּאֲשֶׁר כָּרַע שָׁם נָפַל שָׁדוּד
Between her legs he sank, he fell, he lay still; between her legs he sank, he fell; where he sank, there he fell dead (Judges 5:25/27)

Does this story involve a seduction? Do any commentators shed light on sexual undertones in the story? Is  בֵּין רַגְלֶיהָ a euphemism?

The translation cited, here, is not referenced. From Young's Literal Translation , the narrative is that one party bashed the other's head with a hammer and the second party fell down between the first party's feet. Personally, it seems to me that anyone seeing anything more, or other, than that is not getting the information from the text of scripture.

The translation is literal, בֵּין רַגְלֶיהָ literally means "between her legs", see the birthing reference in Deuteronomy 28:57: וּבְשִׁלְיָתָהּ הַיּוֹצֵת מִבֵּין רַגְלֶיהָ, “the afterbirth that comes out from between her legs.”

Perhaps. Or perhaps it was meant to be a cruel irony. However, the translators of the Septuagint chose the word, ποδῶν (podōn), feet over the Greek word σκέλη (skelē), legs.

Again, you are not substantiating your translation. Young's Literal translates Deut 28:57 as which cometh out from between her feet. These references are deliberately (in scripture) less physical than you want them to be. 'Coming from between the feet' is a deliberately less coarse rendering than your own (it would seem personal unless you can reference it) expression of the Hebrew. Please cite an authoritative source rather than state these translations as your own.

@NigelJ “ In the Song of Deborah, when Yael strikes Sisera, he falls בֵּין רַגְלֶיהָ, which in context likely means “between her feet,”[12] but can also be translated with the more sexual “between her legs.”[13] Indeed, rabbinic midrash says as much (b. Yebamot 103a)” Caryn Tamber-Rosenau says the same thing about the literal translation: https://www.thetorah.com/article/deborah-yael-and-siseras-mother-themech. You could have chosen to read Dan Feffermans sources which also agree with this reading or posted your own answer instead of downvoting and trying to close my question

Related: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/did-ruth-uncover-boaz-feet-or-something-else

@NigelJ - if by "Course" you mean explicit (as in "course language") I have little regard for people's delicate sensibilities in that scripture is often pretty explicit (perhaps including swear words) and contains pornographic depictions vis-a-vis erotic literature.

If you are claiming it is just a cleaner rendering generally, that's fine, but it is not self-evident that one rendering is better than another simply by virtue of not being a euphemism for genitals or not containing sexual innuendo.

This is very much in the eye of the beholder. The translation is often given as "at her feet" but "between her legs" is also understood by several interpreters. It must be admitted that sexual innuendo can be read into the story. Certainly this is the case in the later story of Judith, who similarly gets Holofernes to lower his guard and then kills him.
As far as commentaries go, the most important is found in the Talmud (Nazir 23), which makes it kosher for any Jewish interpreter to follow suit; and many have done so:

The Gemara asks: How is it derived that Yael engaged in sexual
intercourse with Sisera? As Rabbi Yoḥanan said: That wicked one,
Sisera, engaged in seven acts of sexual intercourse with Yael at that
time, as it is stated: “Between her feet he sunk, he fell, he lay;
between her feet he sunk, he fell; where he sunk, there he fell down
dead” (Judges 5:27). Each mention of falling is referring to another
act of intercourse.

Quite a few other commentaries also interpret Yael's wooing of Sisera as sexual. This article gives examples. However, in my view, motherly seduction is the more likely type of sedative than sexual satiation. Yael's goal was to make Sisera sleep so she could kill him. Sisera is clearly depicted as being exhausted from his unsuccessful battle. He comes to Yael's tent seeking water and rest, not sex. She plays the mother's role, offering him milk. He obligingly falls asleep and the rest is history.
But the simple answer is yes, there is sexual innuendo any time a man enters a woman's tent, especially in biblical times. And in this case, some important commentaries do see the seduction of Sisera as sexual.

Thanks a ton for the answer, thoughtful as always! I hadn't considered motherly imagery, that adds a whole other dimension to the story and Deborah's song

@DanFefferman. Or maybe milk have sleep inducing effects.

Seems to me that people are seeing what they want to see. I've read this passage throughout my lifetime (over 70 years) and I never saw such a meaning myself.

@NigelJ I had the same experience until recently.

a simple response would be that women were given great responsibility in the Home. and when she treated him with lordly respect it was all good until he asked her to lie...that might be the best and simplest level with out going "Sod"..this comes into play as a woman Num 5:14 - And the spirit of jealousy come upon him, and he be jealous of his wife, and she be defiled: or if the spirit of jealousy come upon him, and he be jealous of his wife, and she be not defiled:..she did not want to be defiled..or:Deu 22:22 - If a man be found lying with a woman married to an husband, then they shall both of them die, both the man that lay with the woman, and the woman: so shalt thou put away evil from Israel...connecting the patterns is essential and the more "witnesses" to the pattern, obviously the clearer the context becomes.. in scripture women are to cry out if a man "comes upon them"..even if they are by themselves.

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
